# Symfony CSRF Attack Detected even when passing _csrf_token

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, csrf

Here is my form:

```
<form novalidate action="<?php echo url_for('article/submit') ?>" method="POST">
  <?php echo $form['title']->renderRow() ?>
  <?php echo $form['content']->renderRow() ?>
  <?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields() ?>
  <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

And looking at the generated HTML source, the `_csrf_token` IS in fact being rendered. Here is my action:

```
public function executeSubmit(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->forward404Unless($request->isMethod('post'));
  $request->checkCSRFProtection();

  die('submitting post...');
}
```

The error:

```
_csrf_token [CSRF attack detected.]
```

Even in my action if I do a `var_dump($_POST); die;` I get:

```
Array
(
  [title] => string(8) "My title"
  [content] => string(10) "My Content"
  [_csrf_token] => string(32) "<my token here>"
)
```

So the csrf token is definitely being rendered and passed correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Also, is there any documentation for `checkCSRFProtection()` anywhere? The API doc's dont' say anything about it besides acknowledging it's existence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things to check:

(**Source:** From http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/t/17867/)

Be sure you have defined your "secret" in your settings:

```
csrf_secret: ThisIsMySecret  # Unique secret to enable CSRF protection or false to disable`
```

Also, based on what I've gathered from that form post, CSRF protection checking is done automatically in `$this->form->isValid()`, so your call to `$request->checkCSRFProtection()` is unnecessary if you are already checking if the form is valid. If not, add `$this->form->isValid()`.

It would also seem that `$request->checkCSRFProtection()` doesn't work with forms; it's purpose (if I'm correct) is to validate requests served when a user clicks a link. When CSRF protection is enabled, `link_to()` automatically adds CSRF protection to the links it generates. So, basically, the CSRF protection for a form is different for that of a request that didn't originate from a form.

See this ticket for more details: http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/7315

Another ticket that may be of interest: http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/5698

Comment: The problem was that I was trying to check a form using `checkCSRFProtection()` instead of trying to use the `isValid()` method. Thanks for your help. The Symfony 1.4 API Docs don't give ANY details about `checkCSRFProtection()`. Good to know that it only works for `link_to()`. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jakobud: Glad I could help! Yeah, the docs look pretty crappy

Comment: @jakobud: you use `checkCSRFProtection` for cases where there may not be an actual form to validate... for example a simple ajax post request to delete a record. You can see some examples in generated admin modules and the delete action if i recall correctly.